# How to disable REST convention from interfering with my ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

This is my api configuration class:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );
    }
}
```

This is my api controller class:

```
public class RoleController : ApiController
{

    // Some action that works fine...
    // Another action that works fine...

    public Result Delete([FromBody]int RoleID)
    {
        return RoleBL.Delete(RoleID);
    }
}
```

I am calling my actions using `POST` and they are working fine.
But, when I try to call the `Delete` action using `POST` I get the following error:

> 405 Method Not Allowed
>
> The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'.

Clearly, this is because `ApiController` enforces REST convention
which expects `DELETE` verb for `Delete` action.

Now, how do I disable this REST convention constraints
and write my actions in a classic manner?

Comment: That's called `Convention over Configuration`, you can't disable it and you shouldn't even attempt to. Either follow REST or do not use REST names.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HttpPostAttribute` to enforce the Action to accept only `POST`:

```
public class RoleController : ApiController
{       
    [HttpPost]
    public Result Delete([FromBody]int RoleID)
    {
        return RoleBL.Delete(RoleID);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not `POST` to `DELETE` a resource. What a horrible thing to do to the consumers of your api

Comment: @Camilo don't do that. Post your own answer then.

Comment: @Alex I've worked on applications using `POST` instead of `DELETE` because `DELETE` was blocked by firewall policies, so sometimes you don't have too many options.

Comment: @Alex no, going all out on verbs and status codes is a pleasure to consume? If you want to call your API from an HTML form or whatever, you will _have_ to accept POST.

Comment: `don't have too many options` - allow `DELETE` on the firewall would be a good option.

Comment: @Alex that's perhaps nice in a startup where everyone can access the router's config; not so in other environments.

Comment: True, but I wouldn't advocate using inappropriate REST verbs to code around an environmental / network issue.

Comment: @Alex that wouldn't solve problems like HTML forms that can either `GET` or `POST`

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to POST to a http API directly from a HTML form. Use xhr request?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to keep the `REST` conventions while allowing certain clients (like HTML forms) to properly use you actions.
So, you can use a combination of `HttpPostAttribute` and `HttpDeleteAttribute` or `AcceptVerbsAttribute` (which allows multiple verbs) to allow multiple verbs:

```
public class RoleController : ApiController
{       
    [HttpPost, HttpDelete]
    // OR
    [AcceptVerbs("DELETE", "POST")
    public Result Delete([FromBody]int RoleID)
    {
        return RoleBL.Delete(RoleID);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, is there another type of controller class I could inherit that is not rest-enabled?

Comment: I don't want to use the REST but just a classic approach without magic verbs and magic action names

Comment: Using this approach you don't have to? Just `POST` to `Role/Delete/123` (as uncomfortable as that makes me feel)

Comment: @Dusan no, it's not meant to be used like that. You have to either explicitly say the Verb you want to support or change the action name *so that it does not match an HTTP verb*, for example `DeleteRole`, `DeleteEntity`, etc

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want magic verbs and magic action names you can use route attributes.
Delete `config.Routes.MapHttpRoute` and set:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Now **you have to** set the routes manually:

```
[RoutePrefix("~/Role")]
public class RoleController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("~/Delete")]
    public Result Delete([FromBody]int RoleID)
    {
        return RoleBL.Delete(RoleID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case I'd stop using any kind of REST conventions.

Instead of having a Delete method on the Role controller you can have a DeleteRole method and allow POST on it. This way nothing will interfere with what you want to do. Nothing forces you to build a REST api if that's not what you need.

There are several things you could do to still build a nice api.

For example, you could return an IHttpActionResult

your method could look like this:

```
public class RoleController : ApiController
{       
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult DeleteRole([FromBody]int RoleID)
    {
        if ( RoleID <= 0 )
        {
              return BadRequest();
        }

        var deleteResult = RoleBL.Delete(RoleID);
        return Ok(deleteResult);
    }
}
```

You still return the same object but it's wrapped inside an object with a proper http code so your code which deals with the result, won't change much.